# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established in Laravel and pusher.js

Tags: laravel, pusher-js

I am using pusher for Laravel and I want to test results in the localhost. there are some problems with it and I get "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established" error.
my configurations are :

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
```

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver'    => 'pusher',
            'key'       => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY' ),
            'secret'    => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET' ),
            'app_id'    => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options'   => [
//                'cluster'     => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
                'port'      => 6001,
                'scheme'    => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'local',
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    // wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    transports: ['websocket']
});
```

I have searched this error a lot on the internet but I haven't gotten any answers to solve the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested many different ways and I get an answer. I told it's a good idea to share it with you.
I downgraded pusher version and it works now. Downgrade your pusher-js version to 4.3.1.

Comment: you should remove the node_modules folder and then change package.json manually and downgrade the version of this (   "pusher-js": "^4.3.1" )  then install again with npm install.

Comment: i think in my case this is not issue. My issue is little bit changed

Comment: Can you confirm that ..is it necessary to run ```php artisan websocket:serve``` with supervisor? i mean should it work when i run it in terminal manuallly?

Comment: I am not sure about understanding your problem exactly. have you deleted node_modules folder? I run that command withoud supervisor